# android: How to start native activity from command line using am?

Tags: android, android-ndk, native

I know I can start a Java activity by using something like this

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.hellojni/
com.example.hellojni.HelloJni
```

How about a native activity??? I tried to use the similar -n argument from android:name found in AndroidManifest.xml, but it always tells me that Activity class does not exist.

Comment: The technique is the same.  If you are getting that error, you have not manifested and implemented a proper native activity component with that name.

Answer (score 2):

It works just about the same other than your use that android app uri for the activity rather than the uri for you overridden activity.  Just to note both android.intent.action.MAIN and android.intent.action.LAUNCHER worked for me.

am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.hellojni/android.app.NativeActivity

Answer (score 0):

You can launch it using the intent you're showing, as long as it is declared as accessible from the launcher with this, at the application manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

It can be started, using the name declared in the attribute "android:name", for the Activity. Check the SDK for [NativeActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html) for more information.

In the example you're using, however, it's not a native activity, but a regular one, with a linked native library (the example included in the NDK).

I hope this helps!

Comment: I know it's an old question but I still can't seem to get this to work. I have an intent with an native-activity project (the official example from NDK). To avoid name clash, I changed the android.intent.action.MAIN to android.intent.action.NativeActivity.MAIN and redeployed the apk. But then running "adb shell am -a android.intent.action.NativeActivity.MAIN" gives me "Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.NativeActivity.MAIN flg=0x10000000 }"